# WeakHashMap how is the entry _actually_ found after the reference is put on the ReferenceQueue

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references, weakhashmap

A `WeakHashMap` works pretty much as a `WeakReference` coupled with a `ReferenceQueue` - there is zero news about this. Here is a stripped down example of how it is supposed to work:

```
public class ReferenceQueuePlayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReferenceQueue<Referent> q = new ReferenceQueue<>();

        Referent ref = new Referent();
        WeakReference<Referent> weak = new WeakReference<>(ref, q);

        ref = null;

        // wait for GC to reclaim Referent
        while (weak.get() != null) {
            System.gc();
        }

        // this might return null, because ReferenceQueue is notified asynchronously
        // but I am assuming the happy path here 
        Reference<? extends Referent> reference = q.poll();

        // this will be false
        System.out.println(reference == null);
        // this will be true
        System.out.println(reference.get() == null);
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    static class Referent {

    }
}
```

This is exactly how `WeakHashMap` works - it gets notified when the `referent` is reclaimed and the `reference` is put on the `ReferenceQueue`. At some subsequent operation, `expungeStaleEntries` is called, which will basically take elements from this `ReferenceQueue` one by one and act on them.

The problem I have: how can it "act on them" if the `referent` is now gone? This is a `...HASHMap` after all, so in order to remove the element, it must know it's `hashCode`. How can you know the `hashCode` for something that is now gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways. The first one would be a *linear search*.

Since the *referent* is indeed gone and you can't compute the `hashCode` on it, you can search for the `Reference` with `==`, across *all* entries in the `Map`. In the example posted, you could add a few lines like:

```
    WeakReference<Referent> weak = new WeakReference<>(ref, q);
    // <--- this
    System.out.println(weak);

    ref = null;

    while (weak.get() != null) {
        System.out.println("not yet");
        System.gc();
    }

    Reference<? extends Referent> reference = q.poll();
    // <---- and this
    System.out.println(reference);
```

These both will print the same thing, which makes complete sense. So in theory, a `WeakHashMap` could take the `reference` it got (which is actually an `Entry`) and traverse its inner array, until a match is found.

Obviously, this would be slow.

The second approach is the one that `WeakHashMap` *actually* takes. When an `Entry` is first created, it computes the `hashCode` and puts that into a local field:

```
/**
  * Creates new entry.
  */
Entry(Object key, V value,
      ReferenceQueue<Object> queue,
      int hash, Entry<K,V> next) {
    super(key, queue);
    this.value = value;
    this.hash  = hash;
    this.next  = next;
}
```

At this point it knows the `Key`, so it can compute the `hashCode`. When `expungeStaleEntries` is later called:

```
 private void expungeStaleEntries() {
    for (Object x; (x = queue.poll()) != null; ) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Entry<K,V> e = (Entry<K,V>) x;
            int i = indexFor(e.hash, table.length);
```

It already knows the `hashCode`, since it was computed before this. It does not know the `Key`, but there is no need for it either.

This will help to find the bucket where this Entry will be, but to actually find the specific Entry, it can only use `==` on the Entry itself. since `Key` is gone, `equals` is impossible, but that does not matter.